# Android, Kotlin: Recyclerview, how to prevent the last item to be shown, but pass it to the adapter

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have a Recyclerview with a ListAdapter which binds the items, however I have to give to the bind method in the ListAdapter also it's next element as parameter, because it needs some information from the next element. However the last element is not needed to be shown as own list item, because it doesn't contain the kind of information I have to show.

> **EDIT :** *The last item still should be passed to the adapter, because it contains important information about it's previous item*

The RecyclerView just shows the basic item layout without any data from the list instead and if I set the visibility of the last item (it's a constraint Layout) **View.GONE** than it still shows a white space in the Recyclerview.

I use this:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RouteDetailViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val item = getItem(position)

        if (position < itemCount - 1) {
            val nextItem = getItem(position + 1)
            holder.bind(item, nextItem)
        }

    }
```

Now my question is: How may I prevent the Recyclerview to show the last item or the white space?

Let me know, if you need more information or code
Thanks

Comment: use position-1 into bindViewHolder of adapter class while you display your data into recyclerview

Comment: Try inherit from `ListAdapter` and override `getItemCount` method to return `list.size - 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, thank you for your answers they helped me to find the solution.

I modified the constructor of my adapter, which actually is a subclass of the ListAdapter and passed the last list item into the adapter, before I removed it from my list.

I have also modified my onBindViewHolder:

```
 override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RouteDetailViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val item = getItem(position)

        if (position < itemCount - 1) {
            val nextItem = getItem(position + 1)
            holder.bind(item, nextItem)
        }

        else {

            if (lastItem != null) {
                holder.bind(item, lastItem)
            }
        }
    }
```

I hope someone else may find this usefull, too

Answer (score 1):

Best way, to remove the last item from your data list then pass it to adapter  or create adapter with the list already removed item.

```
val myList: MutableList<T> = mutableListOf<T>()
myList.removeAt(mutableListOf.lastIndex)

myAdapter.update(myList)
```

Adapter class

```
   class MyAdapter(private val myData: MutableList<T>):RecyclerView.Adapter<MyViewHolder>() {
       ...


    fun update(myList:MutableList<T>) {
       myData.clear()
       myData.addAll(myList)
       notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
  }
```

OR

in Adapter

```
fun onBindViewHolder (holder: MyViewHolder, pos: Int) {
  if (pos == data.lastIndex) {
    viewHolder.itemView.visibility = GONE

    // OR / AND

    viewHolder.itemView.setHeight(0)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I want to pass the last item of the list to the adapter

Comment: I have already solved my issue, thanks for helping. Mersi shat

Answer (score 0):

private fun deleteItem(position: Int) {

```
mDataSet.removeAt(position)
notifyItemRemoved(position)
notifyItemRangeChanged(position, mDataSet.size)
```

}

Comment: Tnx for your answer, the ListAdapter needs the last item, becaus it contains information about the previous item

Answer (score 0):

If you have used Listadapter then just remove last item by

```
dataset.removeat(dataset.size-1)
```

then call submit method with data set

```
recyclerview.submit(dataset)
```

And if you have simple adapter then Use

```
dataset.removeat(dataset.size()-1);
notifyItemRemoved(dataset.size()-1);
```

Comment: Tnx for your answer. The last item contains important information for the previous item, so I would be able to call it only after the pervious item is bind, correct? Btw. I use ListAdapter

Comment: You need to call it from your activity or say where your recycler view is defined to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

You can override **getItemCount()** method in **ListAdapter** and return **list.size - 1** which prevent to display last item